# Django Orm: найти записи у которых два менеджера ForeignKey, ничего не возвращают

Tags: python, django, django-orm

```
class AModel(models.Model)
    some = CharField()


class BModel(models.Model)
    some = CharField()
    a_model = models.ForeignKey(AModel, models.CASCADE, related_name="b_models")

class CModel(models.Model)
    some = CharField()
    a_model = models.ForeignKey(AModel, models.CASCADE, related_name="c_models")


# Вот теперь мне нужно найти все AModel, у которых
a_model.b_models.all().exists() == False and 
a_model.c_models.all().exists() == False
```

То есть те к которым эти модели ещё не привязаны.

Как-то можно такой запрос составить?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```
q = AModel.objects.filter.objects
q = q.filter(b_models__isnull=False)
q = q.filter(c_models__isnull=False)
q = q.distinct()

result = list(q)
print(result)
```

**isnull** применяется для выявления отсутствующих foreign ключей. [Ссылка на док](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#isnull).

**distinct** применяется для исключения повторений AModel – а они будут, если `isnull=True` и внешних ссылок на конкретный AModel больше одной. [Ссылка на док](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct).

<sub>PS: работоспособность этого кода проверил на своём большом проекте.</sub>